# What are the options for a prepaid SIM card in Singapore?

Tags: cellphones, data-plans, singapore

I'm in Singapore for a week and would like to use data with my iPhone5. What are the options that include enough data for moderate to heavy usage (1-2GB should be enough for the week).

Comment: may i know that if you had only pay S$7? is there any additional charges for it? n how much did it cost for singtel shop to cut the sim card for you?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Singapore has three mobile phone operators and given the small size of the country, their coverage is fairly similar. Their offerings aren't very differentiated for contract plans, but for pre-pay plans there are some differences.

- **[SingTel](http://info.singtel.com/personal/phones-plans/mobile/prepaid/mobile-data)** has a 'Super Surfer Pack' that offers 1 GB of data for S$7 valid for 7 days.
- **[StarHub](http://www.starhub.com/content/broadband/onthemove/maxmobileprepaid.html)** offers a mobile data plan that either costs S$18 for 5 days of unlimited Internet, or a S$32 prepaid SIM with add-on data plans ranging from S$3 to S$32 with different validity lengths and data transfer limits.
- **[M1](http://www.m1.com.sg/M1/site/M1Corp/menuitem.bbba2e1e0cd45957f15a947b3f2000a0/?vgnextoid=78308d63246e9310VgnVCM100000695a230aRCRD&vgnextfmt=pdate:1212040341%3a)** has a similar offering as Singtel, offering 1GB of data for S$7.

All you need to get a pre-pay SIM is your passport and then you can buy the SIM cards from any convenience store, or a company-specific mobile phone shop. I also wrote about [getting Internet access in Singapore on my blog](http://www.ankurb.info/2011/06/19/staying-connected-in-singapore/) - it's a bit out-of-date but may be helpful nevertheless.

Comment: I went with SingTel and am using the 7day, 1GB plan. They don't currently offer nano SIM (iPhone 5) for prepaid, but if you ask in a SingTel shop they will cut the card for you.

Comment: I would recommend purchasing your SIM card at the airport. The vendors are just after you pass through customs.

Answer (score 2):

You can also pre-order SIM cards for collection at Changi Airport: e.g. [SingTel](https://www.singtel.com/personal/products-services/mobile/prepaid-plans/hi-tourist#more), [Starhub](https://topup.starhub.com/preorder/tourist/), [M1](https://www.kkday.com/en-sg/product/12022-singapore-7days-m1-prepaid-4g-sim-card-changi-airport-pick-up).